# How to play two simultaneously notes on the bass guitar?

Tags: electric-bass-guitar

I am learning a song and need help reading the music sheet. I think the bass clef is for piano?  Notes show up one on top of the other. I am assuming a piano player would play both notes with two fingers simultaneously on the left hand. What do I play on bass guitar or do I not follow the bass clef for piano?

Comment: We probably need a little more context in order to answer your question. Answer some questions for us like: Are you playing as part of a band? what style are you playing, what style is the music. I know we don't like to talk about specific pieces usually, but perhaps even a sample of the music?

Comment: You could also tell us if the sheet music was written for bass, or for piano?

Comment: Vertical notes (i.e. on top of each other) on the stave are for chords - two or more notes played tigether.  So yes, use two or more fingers of the left (or fretting) hand to play them. I suspect you have picked a piece that is too complex though... You may like to search for a beginners guide to reading music first.

Comment: It is quite common for bass players to play chords by fretting more than one note with their fretting hand and then plucking more than one string with their plucking hand - a lot like playing a guitar. While it is more difficult to hold down multiple notes on the bass than on guitar, once a player has built up the hand strength it is not too complicated. Tool, Led Zeppelin, Rage Against the Machine, and Ned's Atomic Dustbin, to give just a small sampling, all have songs with bass chords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's commonplace for the bass clef (usually left hand) of piano sheet music to contain more than one note. Usually, but not always, the bass guitarist will play single notes for their part in songs, because someone else is playing the other notes which make up the chords that are the backing. On bass guitars, often, playing two or more notes cause a muddiness in the sound - 6 string basses are better, as the top couple of strings are pitched higher, so one is the norm.

When the sheet music shows more than one note, you can of course play both or all of them on bass guitar; it's not difficult, but you'll probably find the sound is not too clear, so maybe stick to the lower of two or three. Otherwise, ignore that and play notes from the chord/s in each bar, singly.

Comment: That's not necessarily true; there are many examples of bassists playing chords.  Stanley Clarke,Jaco Pastorius, Victor Wooten for example.

Comment: @Shevliaskovic - on a percentage basis, it's more usual to pay single notes. Take 1,000 well known songs... but, point taken, that's why 'not always' is there.

Comment: Yup, I agree; but it is a common misconception among amateur (usually rock) musicians that the bass *should* play *only* single notes.

Comment: Regarding playing "all" of the notes, there is a requirement that there be no more simultaneous notes than there are strings on the bass.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - fair point, but - four is probably the maximum number found on a bass clef (usually), and some of us play 5 string basses! However, a four or even five string chord on bass guitar sounds pretty awful.

Comment: Rock bassists who want to play *Heartbreaker* by Led Zeppelin or *Schism* by Tool or *Bullet in the Head* by Rage Against the Machine should get over the one-note misconception very quickly. Rock bassists who *don't* want to play any those songs should start calling themselves "pop", "folk-rock", or "country" bassists instead.

Comment: @Tim I'd say there are plenty of ways to make larger chords work on electric bass without getting muddy. Complicated chords in lower registers can sound muddy on any instrument, including piano, so if one is playing a left-hand piano part without too thick a tone one has a decent chance of getting away with it, I'd say. Agreed 5-strings are fairly common and five-note left hand chords are rare, just noting that five bass notes could potentially be presented to a four-string player and that would be trickier.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - just a thought about playing 'more notes than strings'. It's entirely possible, and I use it, to play a tapped harmonic in such a way that the open string note AND the harmonic both come out. Chances are both could well be featured in a particular chord, so theoretically it's possible to obtain twice as many notes as strings. I wouldn't bother but sometimes three or four notes from two strings can be effective, and because the harmonics are higher, no muddiness.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do is to use both hands and play by tapping the notes. If the song is written for piano, it might not be easy playable at the bass. It has more limitations, so you might find out that the song cannot be played on the bass.

But, try using both of your hands and see if you can press both notes at the same time.

Some examples of bass tapping:

Comment: Impressive Fur Elise! Would it be playable on a 'normal' 4 or 5 string?

Comment: I doubt that. I think he uses all 7 strings in this song, but it might be playable on a 6 string bass

Comment: I suppose most 7 stringers have a top F rather than a bottom F#? I used to play with a guy on 8 string - F# - F.

Comment: @Tim I'm not 100% sure; I've seen two 7 strings up close and they both had a low F#. But I would prefer a high F